# Using comparative logic in AWS DNS/Route 53 records

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, dns, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

We have a site setup in AWS.  When we bring up a stack for a new release we make it available at a versioned URL.  i.e.

V1 available at `v1.mysite.com`

V2 available at `v2.mysite.com`

etc

**Is it possible to make a single DNS entry that will point to the latest deployed version of my site automatically?**  So, after I deploy V1, I would have two DNS entries:

`v1.mysite.com` which goes to the IP of it's stack

`mysite.com` which redirect to `v1.mysite.com`

Then when I deploy V2, `mysite.com` now redirects to `v2.mysite.com` without me manually having to edit the DNS entry.

In general, can I automatically make DNS entries or make some kind of wildcarded DNS entry that will always point to the highest numbered version of my site currently available in AWS?  It should look at the digits after the `V` for all currently available DNS entries/stacks and make `mysite.com` point to the numerically highest one.

We are using CloudFormation to create our stacks and our DNS (Route 53) entries, so putting any logic in those scripts would work as well.

Comment: Route53 does not provide this type of functionality. Your best bet is to include some logic in your deploy script to update the DNS entry.

Comment: I ended up having to make it a manual deploy step.  If the new stack was going to be the target of the generic DNS entry, a user had to delete the DNS records for the existing mapping before deploying the new stack.  Then the deploy scripts could create the new DNS mapping if desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up must making this a manual step before deploying a new stack.  If the new stack needed to be resovled at `mysite.com`, the deployer has to manually remove the existing mapping.  Then the cloud formation scripts will create the new DNS mapping.

Not ideal but better than a ton of messy logic in cloud formation scripts I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't part of DNS itself, so it's unlikely to be supported by anything on Route53. Your best bet is a script that runs when your new instance starts or is promoted to be the production instance. It's pretty simple using [boto](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/route53.html):

1. Create a new `boto.route53.record.Record`
2. Create a new `boto.route53.record.ResourceRecordSets`
3. Add a change record with the action `UPSERT` and your record
4. Commit the `ResourceRecordSets` (with a simple retry in case it fails)
5. `get_change()` until Route53 replies `INSYNC`
6. Depending on your application you may also want to wait for all the authoritative DNS servers (`dns.resolver.query('your-domain', 'NS')`) at Amazon to know about your change.